# How do I use Pikaday calendar with unique Div's

Tags: javascript, pikaday

I have Div's with the same class name. I can loop through them and console out their unique IDs that have been assigned. I also have code for pikaday that works fine with one Div. I'm now trying to loop through the Div's and assign a pikaday calendar to each one but my code tha worked for one Div isn't working for the multiple divs. I just cannot figure out why.
Thank you for any help.

```
$('.main_records').each(function() {
  var picker = new Pikaday({
    field: this,
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    mainCalendar: 'right',
    onSelect: date => {
    var formatDate = moment(date).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    console.log(formatDate);
    document.getElementsByClass('.main_records').innerHTML = formatDate;
  });
});
```

If I remove this code:

```
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    mainCalendar: 'right',
    onSelect: date => {
    var formatDate = moment(date).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    console.log(formatDate);
    document.getElementsByClass('.main_records').innerHTML = formatDate;
```

pikaday pops up but then I can't assign the selected date to my Div element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `document.getElementsByClass` is not a valid method, you'd need to use: `document.getElementsByClassName`, but that returns a NodeList, not a single element - however you're already using jQuery so we can change the code.

```
$('.main_records').each(function() {
  var currentElement = $(this); // Store reference to current element
  var picker = new Pikaday({
    field: this,
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    mainCalendar: 'right',
    onSelect: function(date) {
      var formatDate = moment(date).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
      console.log(formatDate);
      currentElement.html(formatDate); // Set the innerHTML of the current element
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Answer accepted...it works great! Thank you very much!